# Difference between diameter of a graph vs longest path of the graph

Tags: graphs, terminology

I am curious what is the difference between diameter of a graph vs longest path of a graph. I just read diameter of a graph can be solved using Floyd warshall in O(V^3) while longest path can be calculated in O(V + E) using topological sort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [longest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) of the graph is the longest path between any two vertices. There may be several with the same longest length.

Since you are comparing with the diameter, which is an integer, you probably mean the length of the longest path

The [diameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) is the length of the longest of the shortest path between any two
vertices. That means that you compute the shortest path for any pair
of vertices, and take the longest one of them.

The distance between two vertices being the shortest path, the diameter is the longest distance between two vertices,

Comment: Well, this was a word confusion started by the fact that the question mixed a distance with a path to begin with. But you are right.

Comment: It might be useful to include a small example where the two notions don't coincide.

Comment: I know you know this, but it is not necessary to compute the shortest path distance for every pair of vertices to find out what the diameter is. It is, of course, the obvious way of doing it.

Comment: @Raphael: A triangle works.  In general, $K_n$ has diameter 1 and paths of length $n-1$.

Comment: @Juho Yes. But I believe definitions should always be as simple as possible, the rest being a matter for theorems. But when two properties are equivalent, it is a matter of taste which should be the defining one.

Answer (score 6):

In general, they are not the same thing. Also, for the general graph, it is easy to compute the diameter, but hard to compute the longest path. In the graph below, the diameter is 4. A path from $6$ to $2$ is highlighted, which is of length 4.

[image]

However, there is a longer (simple) path from $6$ to $2$ of length 5.

[image]

Comment: And there's an even longer path of length 7, though not between those two vertices.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yeah, you'll find one between say 7 and 3.

Comment: "hard" meaning NP-hard here.

Answer (score 4):

Topological sort is only defined for directed acyclic graphs so you can't use it to find longest paths in general directed graphs or undirected graphs. Finding the longest path in an undirected graph (in the whole graph or between two specific vertices) is **NP**-hard.  I assume this holds for cyclic directed graphs, too.

Note that it's "unfair" to compare Floyd Warshall with an algorithm for finding the longest single path in a graph. Floyd Warshall computes $\Theta(n^2)$ different things (the length of the shortest path between every pair of vertices) so it's running time is, in a sense, $O(n)$ per answer.